# syntax error on token ;,, expected java

Tags: java

I have just some initialization, and I don't see why this is happening, if anyone can see it, it would be of great help. Thank you!

```
package hr.fer.oop.lab5.exams;

import java.util.List;

public class SheetData {
String jmbag;
String group;
List <String> answers;
OptionalDouble=OptionalDouble.empty();
}
```

Comment: you need to define a name for your `OptionalDouble` variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
OptionalDouble=OptionalDouble.empty();
```

You have to specify field name here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare variable name like:

```
OptionalDouble od = OptionalDouble.empty();
```